# OpenCV for android installation

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, installation

I run fedora on my laptop . I want to use openCV library in my android project which will use the camera to recognize objects captured by the rear camera in real time . I downloaded the opencv4android sdk and added it to the workspace following the steps in this link - http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html#o4a-sdk

I am seeing these build errors:

> [OpenCV Library - 2.4.9] Unable to resolve target 'android-14'

I am also getting this message (and similar ones):

> "Unable to resolve target 'android-11'"

I cannot import the sample examples which came with the OpenCV SDK. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to get help for a problem like this, you're going to want to include the actual errors that you're seeing and any commands that were used to compile the source.

Comment: [2014-06-06 18:05:23 - OpenCV Library - 2.4.9] Unable to resolve target 'android-14'.
I am getting this message and similar ones with "Unable to resolve target 'android-11'"

Comment: @ Lynn Crumbling Thanks for the tips . Really needed them . Any help with the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [answer from here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-opencv/1271wvnfwq/opencv4android-error-with-eclipse-opencv):

> This means you don't have 'android-11' platform installed in your
>   Android SDK. Either install the 'android-11' (aka 'Android 3.0')
>   platform with 'SDK Manager' or make right click on each project in
>   eclipse -> project properties -> Android -> set some other target not
>   older than Android 3.0

Do the same thing from android-14.